# Understanding "No Component" marking on datasheet

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, datasheet, esp32

I am looking at the [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3-mini-1_datasheet_en.pdf) for the ESP32-C3-mini-1 module. Page 24 shows the peripheral schematics for the chip. There are a few components whose values are greyed out and then in parenthesis "NC". According to the datasheet this means no component. Here is a photo of what I am talking about. The bottom left corner where the crystal is positioned is the area of the circuit that I am describing. What does this mean? Is it saying that the components are optional?

Also wondering if how to calculate the value for R7?

[image]

Comment: It means exactly what you think - Those components are 'optional'.  They put space on the PCB for them 'just in case'.   This is very very common practice.   Not everybody needs that crystal.   I actually recognize that schematic above, we just spec'd this very part recently.  This is the 'demo board' schematic.  That's why there's so many jumpers and N/C components.  Gives the user maximum flexibility

Comment: +1 for Kyle's comment. And sometimes you see NP which means "not populated".

Comment: Ok that make sense. I appreciate the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the components are drawn in the schematic and there are places reserved for them on the board, but during board manufacture these components are not assembled on the board.

So they are not needed for basic functionality but if someone wants to try out a feature such as the RTC clock crystal it can be soldered there for experimenting and prototyping purposes.

For R7 you want to look at manufacturer documentation. It will be 5 Mohm to 10 Mohm for certain ESP32 models and must not be used for other ESP32 models.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite common to have components which are not populated on a PCB during manufacturing. They may be omitted for several reasons:

1. The design does not require the component but it could be added later for various reasons including noise immunity, stability, performance, tuning, etc. This is common in prototyping and early product versions.
2. The schematic depicts a **product variation** or version where those components are omitted to save cost or exclude features (that may be on a similar but higher-priced version).
3. Some components may require special handling or processes. The "NC" (also "DNP" (do not populate) and "NP" (not populated)) may just be instructing the PCB assembler that the component is not populated within their production steps (but may be added by another vendor before the product is completed).
4. In the case of an evaluation kit or product sample, non-populated components may be for you to manually populate as/if needed for your particular case. For example, when evaluating a variable voltage regulator, it could be the case that the manufacturer omits components that set the output voltage, leaving that to the evaluator.